# Wordpress Stats Plugin: Display Post Views

Tags: plugins, posts, php, scripts, plugin-jetpack

i'am currently using latest version of jetpack. So the stats plugin is also included in this plugin. But now i want to display the number of views the single post get on the single.php file using the data from Stats plugin included in jetpack. So how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put this into your functions.php file:

```
function userfunc_get_post_views($postID) {
        global $post_stats;
        foreach ( $post_stats as $p ) {
            if ( $p['post_id'] == $postID ) { ?>
                <span class='stats-post-views'>
                    <?php echo number_format_i18n( $p['views']) . ' views'; ?>
                </span>
        <?php }
    }
}
```

and then into your single.php file where you want the views to be displayed:

```
<?php userfunc_get_post_views(get_the_ID()); ?>
```

This will wrap it in a div with the class of stats-post-views so you can style it.